# OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to populate a a linked table but it's not working.

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO typelink (CardId, TypeId) SELECT CardId WHERE CardId=:CardId FROM CardComponent; SELECT TypeId WHERE Type=: tempType FROM CardType",{"CardId":id_name,"tempType": card_type[y]})`

This is the error:

```
OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`, not `SELECT ... WHERE ... FROM ...`.

Also, the syntax with with two separate `SELECT` statements for one `INSERT` is not something I've come across; I doubt it's valid.

Comment: ugh i'm getting another error : OperationalError: 1 values for 2 columns                                                             Is it something wrong with my syntax again?

Comment: @MeccaShabazz: Yes it is. See the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/INSERT_.._SELECT <-- this website has an example that I kind of went off of for my query.

Comment: is this better?                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO typelink (CardId, TypeId) SELECT CardId, TypeId FROM CardComponent, CardType WHERE CardId=:CardId and Type=: tempType",{"CardId":id_name,"tempType": card_type[y]})

Answer (score 0):

To do two independet lookups, you should not use a single SELECT, but two independent subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO typelink (CardId, TypeId)
VALUES ((SELECT CardId FROM CardComponent WHERE CardId=:CardId),
        (SELECT TypeId FROM CardType WHERE Type=:tempType))
```

And the `CardId` value read from the database is the *same* value that you're searching for, so you can just use it directly:

```
INSERT INTO typelink (CardId, TypeId)
VALUES (:CardId,
        (SELECT TypeId FROM CardType WHERE Type=:tempType))
```